# Traduction de "kinetic" pour décrire une gestuelle

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Il s'agit de Prince sur scence. Le mot est employé selon [la deuxième définition proposée par Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kinetic).

> He was kinetic and yet totally in control.

Cela pourrait se traduire par « Il était constamment en mouvement, et pourtant d'une maîtrise totale. », mais je cherche une meilleure version pour "kinetic".

Comment: Je n'arrive pas à saisir le sens du mot "kinetic". Est-ce que le verbe "trembler" s'en approche ou alors c'est un autre sens ?

Comment: @Kii I share your feeling (as I interpret your feeling) that "kinetic" might not be the best word to use here (even in English), especially in light of the use of **yet** because the "yet" implies (**wrongly**, in my opinion) that ""being kinetic"" usually/often means "**not** being totally in control." Regardless (and I wouldn't know the best way to translate it), I think the sense of "kinetic" as used here is more like "He was ... **animated and full of enthusiastic energy (nearly frenetic)** and yet totally in control."

Comment: It's idiomatic (and not the best use of the word kinetic in an idiom in English), so therefore it is going to be harder to translate. I agree with @PapaPoule that the sense is most likely referring to animation and enthusiasm. It's also important not to modulate this improperly. A problematic/awkward idiom in one language should produce a similarly awkward idiom in the target language, so as to not misrepresent the sense of the original text. Although, Merriam Webster does list kinetic in the sense that the OP uses.

Comment: Following PapaPoule, might be "débordant d'énergie"

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax Thanks! It’s probably just me, but certain transitional words/phrases usually prepare me for some sort of opposition or limitation (sometimes even outright contradiction) with a subsequently mentioned notion and my understanding (granted, again just me and not based on the arts) of the meaning of  “kinetic” (or any of its synonyms like “dynamic” or “energetic”) doesn’t call for (or even permit, imo) such a contradictory transition  word/phrase when used with “being in control,” total or otherwise (whereas being frenzied/frenetic, or nearly so, would).

Answer (score 5):

**Frénétique** ou **Passionné**

> Il était frénétique, et pourtant d'une maîtrise totale.

D'après le [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fr%C3%A9n%C3%A9tique) :

> Qui est fait avec une grande ardeur.

Comment: Franchement, vu le sens d’opposition présenté par «and yet» (et bien capté par votre «et pourtant»),  je crois que «frenetic» (et donc votre «frénétique») est le mot juste dans les deux langues. +1!

Comment: @PapaPoule : surexcité ?

Answer (score 4):

**Excité** ou **Surexcité** !

En listant la [demande de précision en anglais](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/84084/what-does-to-be-kinetic-mean-in-context-applied-to-a-person) sur le sens de la phrase, j'ai d'abords pensé au terme [excité](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/excit%C3%A9) qui reflète aussi bien le [sens physicien](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excitation_%28physique%29) du terme que le sens ici recherché.

He was kinetic and yet totally in control.

Et puis, je me suis dit que le mot devait encore être appuyé :

> Il était (très) excité et pourtant complètement maître (de lui-même).

Enfin je me suis rendu compte qu'il existait un mot plus précis encore :

> Il était [surexcité](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/surexcit%C3%A9) et pourtant complètement maître de lui-même.

J'espère que la fin de la phrase ne pose pas trop de problème.

Comment: +1 Oui, d’après moi "surexcité" capte bien un état entre l'excitation et la frénésie avec un seul mot qui justifie toujours le sens d'opposition exigé par le "and yet/et pourtant" (encore mieux, ça tombe mème peut-être entre "presque frénétique" et "très excité" mais même sinon c pas glave)

Answer (score 3):

On a suggéré :

> Il était constamment en mouvement, et pourtant d'une maîtrise totale.

Plutôt bien selon moi. En réfléchissant davantage au contexte et au sens en [langue anglaise](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/84084), je trouve que c'est davantage idiosyncratique qu'idiomatique que ce propos. Mais chose certaine, il s'agit d'une *ballerine professionnelle*, et elle ne s'exprime pas comme une physicienne, pas plus qu'elle ne décrit *Prince* comme un électron libre sur scène :

> Hautement dynamique mais toujours d'une grande précision dans le
>   mouvement.

La traduction n'a pas à être aussi légère que le pas au ballet, et je préfère une adaptation bien personnelle, vu le contexte. Je peux imaginer l'[auteure](https://books.google.com/books?id=OLLsAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT223&ots=Zcj1FZhAxO&dq=%22He%20was%20kinetic%20and%20yet%20totally%20in%20control.%22&pg=PT223#v=onepage&q=%22He%20was%20kinetic%20and%20yet%20totally%20in%20control.%22&f=false) s'exprimer ainsi de l'artiste dont elle traite et dit vouloir émuler la démarche artistique. Enfin dynamique (*dynamic*) était un des sens présenté au dictionnaire en question pour *kinetic*. La deuxième partie de la phrase appuie davantage l'idée de mouvement que le texte d'origine, et non celle d'une quelconque retenue ou d'une maîtrise d'on ne sait quoi ; sa formulation (*dans*) est peut-être plus ou moins courante, mais on aime.

Answer (score -3):

> Il était cinétique et encore totalement en contrôle.

Comment: Google translate est parfois utile mais produit ici du charabia ...

Comment: Non, ça, c'est un galimatias d'anglicismes. Être cinétique ne veut rien dire, et être en contrôle, c'est de la traduction digne des séries de Nickelodeon que regarde mon petit garçon : bouillie pour téléchat. ;-)

Comment: « En contrôle » pour l'anglais *in control*, c'est du québecois ? Parce qu'en France ça ne se dirait pas.

Comment: @Gilles et kantz Comme indiqué dans mon premier commentaire, la réponse de user9659 ne contient que ce que google translate produit avec la phrase initiale. Rien qui vaille la peine d'être discuté.